# Listing PID of sleeping processes

Tags: process

I've been reading about processes for a few hours now and I've got a question I'm not able to answer.

How can I display the PID of sleeping processes and also determine and list their number ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `ps` tool to list all processes and their state:

```
ps -eo s,pid
```

If we want to parse this, we need to remove the header:

```
ps h -eo s,pid
```

Now we are going to pipe it to an awk command so that we can only print the pids with a state of "S" (sleeping):

```
ps h -eo s,pid | awk '{ if ($1 == "S" || $1 == "D") { print $2 } }'
```

And now you have a newline separated list of process IDs that are sleeping.

Do with it what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this commend

```
ps o state,command axh | grep "^[SD]" | cut -b 3-
```